# Can the Off-Topic Flag Include a Reason that Is "This Is a Request for Resources"?

Tags: feature-request, resource-request, flagging

Right now, the off-topic reasons include:

- Basic questions on spelling, meaning or pronunciation are off-topic as they should be answered using a dictionary. See: Policy for questions that are entirely answerable with a dictionary.
- Proofreading questions are off-topic unless a specific source of concern in the text is clearly identified. See: Alternative websites for proofreading.
- This question should include more details than have been provided here. Please edit to add the research you have done in your efforts to answer the question, or provide more context. See: Details, Please.
- Blatantly off-topic (this question has nothing to do
  with learning the English language).
- This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network.

Since requesting resources is currently still considered off-topic, could we add this as a reason for flagging?

Otherwise, I've currently been using the "This question should include more details" and posting the community list of resources in the comments, but I have a feeling that this is not what this reason had been intended for.

[image]

Comment: You could flag it for migration to [meta.ell.se] - I think we decided a while back resource requests are OK on meta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick example of the difference between clicking on the "close" link at the bottom of a question and clicking on the "flag" link. [Casting close and reopen](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) votes is a privilege that requires 3000 reputation, which is why you only see "flag" as an option and not "close".

Once you have enough reputation, you will see a close link and it will pop up a dialog like this:

[image: Vote to Close Dialog]

Clicking on the "off-topic" reason will bring up the dialog in JR's answer. If your reason for flagging doesn't fall into the off-topic reasons in the dialog that comes up when you flag to close, then you should flag it for the mod team to look at as J.R. recommended. Flagging for moderator intervention allows you to write an explanation of why the other options weren't helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The merits of this idea can be discussed, of course, but don't forget that the Other reason is always available, and you can use that for when you flag such questions.

[image]

Comment: Interestingly enough, I do not have this option. Is more rep needed for this option to appear or is this option SE-specific, perhaps?

Comment: I wondered about that. I checked on a site where I have less than 1000 rep points, and the "Other" option was available for me there. Note: It appears _after_ I click on the **off-topic because....** option.

Comment: I added a picture to my OP for clarification.

Comment: Most interesting. There are other people who know more about the mechanics of SE than I do. Hopefully the mystery will be solved soon.

Comment: I think the difference is between "flagging to close" and "voting to close" @TeacherKSHuang

Comment: @ColleenV - Yup, I think that’s it. That being the case, a solution would be to not flag to close, but to use the **In need of moderator intervention** option on the previous screen, and then simply explain that this is a question asking about resources.

Comment: Thanks, @ColleenV. I haven't noticed a "Voting to Close" option, but I will keep an eye out.

Comment: @J.R., Yes, I see what you mean.